# Prisma upsert or update typing not accepting same column names that are accepted for create method

Tags: prisma

On Prisma, I have a session model as follows

```
  export type sessionsCreateInput = {
    id?: bigint | number
    hash: string
    user_id: bigint | number
  }
```

this is accepted with no type issues:

```
        await prisma.sessions.create({
          data: {
            hash,
            user_id: id,
          },
        });
      }
```

however, when updating or upserting as follows, I get yelled at for type issues:

```
        await prisma.sessions.update/upsert({
          where: {
            user_id: id, // <---- linter yells here
          },
          data: {
            hash,
          },
        });
```

the error I get is: `Type '{ user_id: bigint; }' is not assignable to type 'sessionsWhereUniqueInput'. Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'user_id' does not exist in type 'sessionsWhereUniqueInput'.ts(2322) index.d.ts(6213, 5): The expected type comes from property 'where' which is declared here on type '{ select?: sessionsSelect | null | undefined; data: (Without<sessionsUpdateInput, sessionsUncheckedUpdateInput> & sessionsUncheckedUpdateInput) | (Without<...> & sessionsUpdateInput); where: sessionsWhereUniqueInput; }'`

and sessionsWhereUniqueInput is defined like so:

```
  export type sessionsWhereUniqueInput = {
    id?: bigint | number
  }
```

how do I allow a search using the user id? Should I make sessions unique by user id by making user id a primary key?

Answer (score 0):

`update`/`upsert` are meant to update single rows that are uniquely identified. `user_id` is not suitable to identify a single row.

If you want to update multiple rows (or at least specify the `where` condition in a way that it is not guaranteed to be a single row), better use `updateMany`.